How to make multiple assertion in one line in Playwright?

In Cypress this is easy because I can use .and and I can chain 2 assertion:
checkFields() {
  this.heading().should('be.visible').and('contain.text', 'test')
}

But in Playwright I get the error: Property 'toContainText' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'
async checkFields() {
  await expect(this.heading).toBeVisible().toContainText('test')
}

How can I do assertion in the same way like in Cypress without using the second line?

How is this.heading defined? If you select by text, then you can chain two assertions in one line, essentially, something like await expect(page.getByRole("h1", {name: "test"}).toBeVisible(). Also, if you're ultimately taking an action on it, like clicking, running a .click() action implicitly checks visibility. So the question needs more info/context to be fully answerable. There's also the .and() locator method which lets you chain locators, which are implicit assertions.

Not sure why this has been closed, seems to me a valid question for anybody coming from Cypress background.

Playwright doesn't have chained assertions. You just need to use as many asserts as you have.
checkFields(){
  await expect(heading).toBeVisible();
  await expect(heading).toHaveText("test");
}

If you want to have both of them validated even if one may fail - use expect.soft https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#soft-assertions
checkFields(){
  // Make a few checks that will not stop the test when failed...
  await expect.soft(heading).toBeVisible();
  await expect.soft(heading).toHaveText("test");

  // Avoid running further if there were soft assertion failures.
  expect(test.info().errors).toHaveLength(0);
}


"Playwright doesn't have chained assertions", mentioned by the other answer, is technically true, but is missing a critical point: all Playwright locator actions are implicit assertions, and will lead to clear error messages when they fail. And since locators are chainable, Playwright does have chained assertions.
When you do
await page.getByRole("h1", {text: "test"}).click();

if no <h1>text</h1> element is found within the allotted timeout, the test will fail as expected with a descriptive log, just as if an expect() assertion had failed.
Playwright will also throw if the element was found in the document, but the .click() action on that element could not be completed, likely because the element wasn't actionable (in a disabled state, not visible, etc). In other words, .click() is an implicit assertion that the element is in an actionable state.
If you look at a typical Playwright test case, even if there are only a few explicit expect() assertions, there are probably 8-10 implicit assertions that need to be true before control flow even reaches the explicit expect()s at the end of the test.
With that in mind, how you defined this.heading matters. If you define it as such (following best practice .getByRole(), which is an accessibility-first, user-visible assertion), then you will assert all of your conditions in one line, at least as far as the assertion is concerned:
this.heading = page.getByRole("h1", {name: "test"});
// ...
await expect(this.heading).toBeVisible();

This boils down to the one-liner:
await expect(page.getByRole("h1", {name: "test"})).toBeVisible();

This validates a few things:

The element is an <h1> element.
The element has text content containing "test" (you can pass exact: true if you don't want a substring match).
The element is visible (does not have other elements on top of it and has a non-zero bounding box).

On the other hand, if you defined this.heading more broadly, for example, page.locator("h1"), then you'd need to use .locator() or .filter() to assert its text as well as visibility, which can be done in a chained manner (but I don't recommend doing this; better to use getByRole):
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.46.1

test("Header has text 'test'", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent("<h1>test</h1>");
  const heading = page.locator("h1"); // kinda vague, not recommended

  // Use chaining on the *locator*, not on the assertion!
  await expect(heading.locator("text=test")).toBeVisible();
});

Of course, you can make this as complex as you want:
test("Header has text 'test' and some other stuff for demonstration", async ({
  page,
}) => {
  await page.setContent('<h1 class="foo">test <span>bar</span></h1>');
  const heading = page.locator("h1"); // kinda vague, not recommended

  // Use chaining on the *locator*, not on the assertion!
  await expect(
    heading
      .locator("text=test")
      .filter({has: page.locator("span").locator("text=bar")})
      .locator(".foo:scope")
      .or(page.locator("etc etc"))
  ).toBeVisible();
});

Now you have a chained assertion, only it's not where you expected it to be.
Now, I don't really recommend this pattern. If the assertion fails, it'll be unclear which predicate failed:
Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✘  1 …1 › Header has text 'test' and some other stuff for demonstration (5.1s)


  1) pw1.test.js:3:1 › Header has text 'test' and some other stuff for demonstration 

    Error: Timed out 5000ms waiting for expect(locator).toBeVisible()

    Locator: locator('h1').locator('text=test').filter({ has: locator('span').locator('text=bar') }).locator('.foo').or(locator('etc etc'))
    Expected: visible
    Received: <element(s) not found>
    Call log:
      - expect.toBeVisible with timeout 5000ms
      - waiting for locator('h1').locator('text=test').filter({ has: locator('span').locator('text=bar') }).locator('.foo').or(locator('etc etc'))


      14 |       .locator(".foo")
      15 |       .or(page.locator("etc etc"))
    > 16 |   ).toBeVisible();
         |     ^
      17 | });
      18 |

So although this proves the concept, it's still better to break operations onto different lines and keep your locators tight, user-visible and simple, without too much chaining.

As somewhat of a detour, a common antipattern in Playwright tests are redundant assertions. If you can click an element, you don't need to assert that it's visible--it has to be visible if you can click it. With this in mind, you'll find that many chained assertions aren't necessary in the first place--Playwright is doing a lot of asserting at every step to make sure the app behavior is as you intend it to be.
Taking another step back, it's OK to use less chaining nowadays. Playwright uses it in defining locators, but in modern async JS programming, using await on every line, using plenty of intermediate variables, and not chaining things is considered perfectly readable and elegant, using a more imperative style for libraries like this. Cypress is an older library, written when JS was (arguably somewhat unhealthily) obsessed with fluent programming and heavy chaining. The ecosystem has moved away from that somewhat, taking a more mature, balanced approach to different programming styles and paradigms.

Playwright does not currently provide a built-in mechanism for chaining assertions in a single fluent-style statement like .and() or similar. Each assertion, such as toBeVisible() or toHaveText(), must be made individually or grouped logically in custom ways(like in the following example).
Custom Fluent-Style Assertion Chaining
If you really want a chaining syntax, you can create a custom helper class for chained assertions.
Here's an example:
import { expect, Locator } from "@playwright/test";

class FluentExpect {
  constructor(private locator: Locator) {}

  async toBeVisible() {
    await expect(this.locator).toBeVisible();
    return this; // Return the object for chaining
  }

  async toHaveText(expectedText: string | RegExp) {
    await expect(this.locator).toHaveText(expectedText);
    return this; // Return the object for chaining
  }

  async toHaveCount(expectedCount: number) {
    await expect(this.locator).toHaveCount(expectedCount);
    return this; // Return the object for chaining
  }
}

// Usage Example
import { test } from "@playwright/test";

test("fluent assertion example", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://example.com");

  const header = page.locator("h1");
  const fluentExpect = new FluentExpect(header);

  await (
    await (await fluentExpect.toBeVisible()).toHaveText("Example Domain")
  ).toHaveCount(1);
});

